# How to get the QED symbol without using the proof environment

Tags: code, proof-package, bullets

I want to get the QED symbol at the right end of the proof without using the proof environment and I want the QED symbol inside \begin{itemize}... \end{\itemize} environment. Is it possible? Thanks you,

Comment: By "proof bullet", do you mean the open-square symbol that's generated at the end of a `proof` environment? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico yes thats what I meant. did I call it wrong? you can the post if you dont mind. Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with using the `proof` environment for proofs?

Comment: @egreg because I want the proof itemized like (a) Proof of integral..... (b) Example..... (c) Related integral. Having the proof environment gives me hard time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the [QED symbol] at the right [hand] end of the proof without using the `proof` environment. ... I want the [QED symbol] inside an `itemize` environment.

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm} % for \qedsymbol macro
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1][1-5] \hfill\qedsymbol
\item \lipsum[2][1-4] \hfill\qedsymbol
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just added the package and typed \hfill\qedsymbol at the end of the proof and turned out perfect. Thank you

Comment: Package `amsthm` also offers the `qedhere` macro

Comment: @user94293 - I don't think that `\qedhere` is usable outside a `proof` environment -- and inside an `itemize` or `enumerate` environment.